# How to set up OnMapLoadedCallback GoogleMaps

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to know when everything I have being loaded into my googlemap fragment has loaded everything. This is what my code currently looks like

```
public class MainMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback {

GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_map);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    //addLatestLocations();

   // TestVectorQuery();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
            new LatLng(32.0516, -78.925), 3));
    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapLoaded() {
    //SetMapMarker(26.1333, 80.1500);
    //Whatever I want to do

}
```

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this; however, when I try to do something within onMapLoaded() nothing happens, so it seems that the callback isn't properly set. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a native fragment (`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment`) and `getFragmentManager()` in a `FragmentActivity`. That does not work. Either change the fragment to `SupportMapFragment` and use `getSupportFragmentManager()`, or change your activity to inherit from `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

try to use support fragment because it works for me .
**below is my code run successfully.**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_map);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("your title")
                    .snippet("your desc")
                    .position(new LatLng(-22.2323,-2.32323))
            );
        }
    });
}
```